# python tkinter updating the combo box programmatically

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

When I print the list that I am setting the Combobox to I am getting an updated list based on the available com ports, however the values in the drop down box are not working. I have a feeling that it is because I am using customtkinter.... I really hope not. Does anyone see what is happening here?

```
import customtkinter
from ConnexLink import findcomports, recievesignal, closeserialport
import serial

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.title("Connex Link")

def runfindcomports(afterfirstrun=True):
  ports=[]
  for info in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
      port1=str(info)#sets the com port to port1
      ports.append(port1[0:4])
  if afterfirstrun:
    combobox_1['values']=ports
    print('why is it not working')
    print(ports)
  return(ports)
ports=runfindcomports(False)

onoroff = False
def onswitch():
  global onoroff
  global ser
  if onoroff:
    onoroff=False
    ser.close()
  else:
    onoroff=True
    print('on')
    ser = serial.Serial(combobox_1.get(),9600,timeout=2)  # open serial port
    
  
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, justify=customtkinter.LEFT,text='Vibrac')
label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

combobox_1 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(frame_1)
combobox_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
combobox_1.set("Select Com Port")
combobox_1['values']=ports

switch_1 = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=frame_1, command=onswitch,text='receive',)
switch_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, command=runfindcomports,text='refresh',)
button_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

text_1 = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=frame_1, width=300, height=300)
text_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

def textfilter(bytes):
  text=str(bytes)
  text=text[2:]
  text=text.split('\\',1)[0]
  return text

def printline():
  global onoroff
  if onoroff:
    line = ser.readline()
    if len(line) > 2:
      text_1.insert("end",textfilter(line)+'\n')
  app.after(500,printline)


app.after(500,printline)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to rewrite your example to use some hard-coded data rather than relying on the `serial` and `ConnexLink` modules?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?  Are the ports not appearing in the combobox at all, or is there some problem when you select them from the list?  (I'm rather suspicious of the code involving `port1[0:4]` - that cannot possibly work if the name of the port is of a different length.)

Comment: You always have afterfirstrun=False.

Comment: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in CustomTkinter library. You can use `configure()` instead of `__setitem__` like this.

```
combobox_1.configure(values=ports)
```

What about reporting this [here](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues)?
I'm not a CTk user or developer, but I analyzed the bug. The parameter lists of the `configure()` methods of the CTk widgets do not conform to the convention of the tkinter base class, as you can see in [this](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/v5.1.2/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_combobox.py#L221) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1695).

Comment: Not sure I would describe that as a CustomTkinter bug. The code in the question appears to be where the bug lies: combobox_1['values']=ports

Comment: @CliveBostock, what do you mean? The ```combobox_1['values']=ports``` calls ```CTkComboBox.configure({'values': ports})``` and the ```CTkComboBox.configure()``` does not get the ```values``` as a keyword argument because it gets ```{'values': ports}``` as the ```require_redraw``` argument. I'm VERY CERTAIN it's a CustomTkinter bug.

Comment: Check the syntax for assigning values: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/combobox

Comment: I know that. I'm saying ```CTKComboBox``` should follow the Tkinter convention. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#setting-options).

Comment: If CustomTkinter behaves according to the CustomTkinter docs, then, it can't be described as a *bug* in CustomTkinter.